# Having problems extending Quill

Tags: import, ecmascript-6, quill, parchment

I'm hitting some problems extending Quill.

I want to modify the `List` and `ListItem` classes in Quill, so I tried to copy `formats/list.js` into my code base as a starting point. I then import my local copy and register it with Quill like so...

```
import { List, ListItem } from './quill/list';

Quill.register({
    'formats/list': List,
    'formats/list/item': ListItem
}, true);
```

However, when I attempt to create a list in the editor the code crashes in the List class with the following error:

```
ParchmentError {message: "[Parchment] Unable to create list-item blot", name: "ParchmentError"}
```

This happens on this line... https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/formats/list.js#L99

I assume it relates to the imports I was forced to change, but I can't figure out what's wrong. I've not made any other changes to list.js. The original file has the following:-

```
import Block from '../blots/block';
import Container from '../blots/container';
```

Which I changed to this:-

```
import Quill from 'quill';
let Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
let Container = Quill.import('blots/container');
```

Is the way I am importing wrong? What is causing the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out (well a colleague did).

I needed to import Parchment like so :-

```
let Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');
```

instead of `import Parchment from 'parchment';`

This is because you'll end up with a different static Parchment class to the one used internally to Quill, so asking Quill for it's instance ensures you are both working with the same one (ie, the one where the blots were registered).

Comment: How can I specify the type here?

Answer (score 2):

I came across that problem a couple hours ago.

In Quill's source code, `List` is a default export while `ListItem` is a named export.

So your import should look like this:

```
import List, { ListItem } from './quill/list';
```

Be sure to export them appropriately on your custom `list.js` file.

Good luck!

Comment: Let me know if it still doesn't work so I can help you more. If this has solved your problem, consider marking this answer as the correct one. I'm new on SO and it would help me out too :-) thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'd changed the exports in my copy so the above was fine. I figured out it was related to the Parchment import, so I've posted an explanation.