# Custom video blot for Quill

Tags: angular, webpack, quill

I'm trying to write a custom blot for Quill so that we can add HTML5 video tags to the editor. I have a working version of this code which works fine in development mode but fails to compile when creating the Angular AOT build.

The error I'm getting is

```
ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (31,26): Cannot find name 'Quill'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (32,22): Cannot find name 'Quill'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (33,21): Cannot find name 'Quill'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (37,22): Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'typeof VideoBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (46,22): Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'typeof VideoBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (67,19): Property 'blotName' does not exist on type 'typeof VideoBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (68,19): Property 'tagName' does not exist on type 'typeof VideoBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (73,22): Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'typeof AudioBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (82,22): Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'typeof AudioBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (103,19): Property 'blotName' does not exist on type 'typeof AudioBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (104,19): Property 'tagName' does not exist on type 'typeof AudioBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (121,20): Property 'blotName' does not exist on type 'typeof SourceBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (122,20): Property 'tagName' does not exist on type 'typeof SourceBlot'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (125,9): Cannot find name 'Quill'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (126,9): Cannot find name 'Quill'.

ERROR in /workspace/workspace/my-app/app/view/common/quillComponent.ts (127,9): Cannot find name 'Quill'.
```

The blot is defined in quillComponent as

```
    let BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');
    let Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');
    let Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
    class VideoBlot extends BlockEmbed {

        static create(value) {
            this.cache = {};
            let node = super.create();
            node.setAttribute('controls', '');
            node.setAttribute('controlsList', 'nodownload');
            node.setAttribute('style', 'max-width:720px');
            node.setAttribute('player-source', value.src);
            let src = document.createElement('source');
            src.setAttribute('src', value.src);
            node.appendChild(src);
            this.cache.length = 1;//94 + value.src.length;
            return node;
        }

        deleteAt(index: number, length: number) {
            super.deleteAt(0, 1);
        }

        length() {
            return 2;
        }

        static value(node) {
            return {
                controls: node.getAttribute('controls'),
                controlsList: node.getAttribute('controlsList'),
                style: node.getAttribute('max-width:720px'),
                src: node.getAttribute('player-source')
            };
        }
    }
    VideoBlot.blotName = 'clbvideo';
    VideoBlot.tagName = 'video';
    Quill.register(VideoBlot);
```

The imports for quillComponent are

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { GlobalService } from "../../service/global.service";
```

And adding the video to the editor is done through

```
this.quill.insertEmbed(this.range.index + 1, 'clbvideo', {
                src: this.urlText
            }, "user");
```

I have tried many, many different ways of importing Quill and the other dependencies into our quillModule but none of them actually work correctly. I tried almost any suggestion from these two:
[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086454/having-problems-extending-quill)
[Reference 2](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1233)

We use webpack and @ngtools/webpack for processing our typescript sources.

If relevant, this is the tsconfig for our AOT build

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["dom","es2015"],
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "core-js"
    ]

  },

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot/",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
  }
}
```

and this is our AOT webpack config

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var helpers = require('./config/helpers');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
var ngtools = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "./scssStyles.css"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './app/polyfills.js',
        'vendor': './app/vendor.ts',
        'app': './app/main-aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('prod'),
        filename: "./[name].js"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },


    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=./assets/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: '@ngtools/webpack'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                include: /\.json$/,
                loaders: ["json-loader"]
            }
        ],

    },

    plugins: [

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new ngtools.AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: helpers.root('./tsconfig.aot.json'),
            entryModule: helpers.root('./app/app.module.ts#AppModule')
        }),

        new ExtractTextPlugin("./styles.css"),
        extractSass,

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

And this are the quill parts of package-lock.json

```
"quill": {
  "version": "1.3.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/quill/-/quill-1.3.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-Tudr3tPSPr64J+Fnr8hsNKbi5e2xueyLROmemOIsIsUIeX+WU7LtA22HWRRHr2gGasqxhah2NzFGe9N32eJkMg==",
  "requires": {
    "clone": "2.1.1",
    "deep-equal": "1.0.1",
    "eventemitter3": "2.0.3",
    "extend": "3.0.1",
    "parchment": "1.1.0",
    "quill-delta": "3.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "quill-delta": {
      "version": "3.6.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/quill-delta/-/quill-delta-3.6.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jSD448mqyDevX0FhdjNppMLHl67vXEzZEDjQrtkfDXI6s6e3WJkJOZpYiVhqxLl4HcYNeAhFT+fhAeX8ef7Cew==",
      "requires": {
        "deep-equal": "1.0.1",
        "extend": "3.0.1",
        "fast-diff": "1.1.1"
      }
    }
  }
},


"@types/quill": {
  "version": "0.0.31",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/quill/-/quill-0.0.31.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-2Y0Pr5SSNf7kpD4mWMPSYYYyVTLbBNn99DtEYzZ1hlEry1fiWCJYLTYSoGTgPvYiRU4JNRi9LYW0EOV60jN9yA=="
},
```

FYI: I also tried using the latest version of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by looking at the primeng code. All I needed to do was declare Quill instead of trying to import it:

```
declare var Quill: any;
```